# Analysis of this (palindrome) sequence

Tags: subsequences

This may be a simple problem ultimately.

I am picturing a “rule” of “relative enumeration”.

Let’s say you start with “19”.

This means, there was another choice you missed - implying that you will input “1” and “9” in some order, you could also have done “91” - so now you do it, to balance it out. Now you have:

“1991”.

But now, there is another “option” you missed, which is again, implicit - you could have done the whole reflective / palindrome thing, but still, started with 9 instead of one - “91” first - then you would have gotten “9119”. So you do that next, to “balance it out”:

“19919119”.

And again:

1991911991191991

Clearly, the formula is to duplicate the string and take the “complement” - the inverse image. But the general formula may be different when working with more than 2 digits, for example.

What interests me are ways to interpret the substrings, and clarify a pattern there -

91191991 -

can be read a few ways. It can be read:

911 - 91 - 99 - 1

In which case, the pattern says something like “all possible combinations” but under certain constraints (I’m trying to figure out what those are) - it appears like the lowest digit cannot exist alone in the “lowest” (last) *place* (the final ‘1’) - *and* (at least so far) the highest digit (‘9’) always must *lead* - and maybe also that as ‘9’ is the *leader*, the sequence for some reason is “finished” (on this iteration) at ‘911’, and not ‘999’, for example (which may be implied to exist in a longer sequence starting with 9111 - but there may be other possibilities).

Another way to subdivide this: 19919119

Is like this:

1 - 99 - 19 - 11 - 9

Here we clearly see that this is all possible combinations of 1 or 2 choices of 2 digits.

I am curious to know a generalization of this.

We have *a* rule, but we realize it is equivalent to some other rules. How many other rules? And why? Where does this take us, in higher level formal languages theory - perhaps categorical (category theory) computer science?

Thank you

Comment: 1. I don't see how this is a question about computer science, or why it needs to be answered from a CS perspective.  It sounds like a matter of pure math.  I recommend that you either [edit] the question to clarify how this is in scope for CS.SE, or delete the copy here and post on Math.SE.  2. "I am curious to know a generalization" sounds too vague and open-ended to be a good fit here.  Our site works best for specific, answerable questions where answers can be objectively evaluated (in particular, there are clear criteria for what constitutes an acceptable answer).

Comment: 3. I'm not sure how to answer "how many rules?"  It depends what space of rules you allow, how you allow rules to be expressed, and under what conditions you consider two rules to be the same.